# Criar List em javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma `view` e dentro dessa `view`, tenho meus `scripts`, preciso criar uma função que crie uma `lista` da minha `ViewModel` ex: `public static List<ContatosViewModel> ListaContatos = new List<ContatosViewModel>();` porém, em `javascript` eu não consigo fazer isso, existe `list` em `javascript`? e como eu posso criar uma `lista`, usando uma `ViewModel`

Estou querendo pegar dados de um grid e acrescentar a uma `lista` tudo isso através de uma função em javascript, porém não sei criar uma list em javascript

Comment: O que você quer fazer na sua página?

Comment: Quero pegar dados de um grid e acrescentar a uma lista, porém isso através de uma função me javascript, porém n sei criar essa list

Comment: Apresente o seu código, não está muito claro o que você está tentando fazer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você usar js puro, pode criar um array de objetos anônimos, exemplo:

```
var test = [ { nome: 'João', idade: '23'}, { nome: 'Henrique', idade: '18'} ];
```

ou um array de números

```
var test = [1,2,3,4];
```